# Totoise SVN externals in subfolders are not recognized for commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, external, commit, subdirectory

Dear Stackoverflow people,

I'm including a bigger number of source-files from a library as externals. I thought it could be useful to have them sorted within subfolders.

Within a project-folder lib the are external-properties set like this:
http://server:81/lib_origin/xxx/yyy/file.foo@233155 xxx/yyy/file.foo

Update is working, but if I change a external locally I can't commit it back to the external's origin, there is no commit button on the file file.foo, nor on folder xxx or yyy.

Do you have any idea why?

Best Regards,

Simon Filgis

Answer (score 1):

got this from SVN mailing list:

"This is a new option in the TortoiseSVN client Settings > Advanced page called BlockPeggedExternals, which is set to true by default. If you change it to false, you'll be able to commit local externals back to their non-external version."

Maybe it helps someone...